# Wildfly in eclipse does not use heap params set in standalone.conf

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I have got wildfly runtime configured in eclipse and hit a need to increase the default heap params. As the server is running in standalone mode so changed the Xms & Xmx settings in standalone.conf . When i start the server outside eclipse using standalone.sh , i can see the correct/updated heap params are used but when i launch the runtime from eclipse it keeps using the default params.

Tried re-adding the runtime multiple times and restarting eclipse as well. Any hints ?

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but I would guess eclipse doesn't use the `standalone.sh` to launch WildFly. I'm assuming though you're using JBoss Tools.

Comment: Please try to change values in eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesnt use wildfly's standalone.conf or standalone.bat, on the server view go to open launch configuration and add the params in program arguments.

```
-mp "C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules" -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b localhost --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone -
```

Add your params there